# Load only N lines of a CSV

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I've a function for load OHCLV data from CSV, at the moment the function grabs all values, and return them, and that's works

What i would like is return only the last `N` values.

For example of 1000 values i need only the last 100.

CSV appears like that:

```
date,open,high,low,close,volume
2013-03-25 16:00:00,76.31,77.5,76.31,77.5,117.65500211
2013-03-25 16:15:00,77.61,77.89,77.1,77.1,36.04786927
[...]
2022-12-22 17:15:00,16646.0,16649.0,16611.0,16623.0,37.57992574
2022-12-22 17:30:00,16626.0,16626.0,16585.0,16608.0,14.26339254
```

Here's the function

```
const getOHCLVData = async (path) => {
  const res  = await fetch(path);
  const resp = await res.text();
  const cdata = resp.split('\n').slice(1).map((row) => {   // slice(1) skip the header
    const [date, open, high, low, close, volume] = row.split(',');
    return {
      time: new Date(`${date}`).getTime() / 1000,
      open: open,
      high: high,
      low: low,
      close: close,
      volume: volume,
    };
  });
  return cdata;
};

// Call function
getOHCLVData(myfile.csv)
```

i should try add a new argument to function and do something like that: `cdata.lenght - NumberValue`

Any suggestion?

Comment: change `.slice(1)` to `.slice(-100)` - negative values pulls from the end of the array.

Comment: you should learn how to work with unix streams. standard input, standard output and such. and to get only the last part of a file you can use a program called tail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an amendment to *Randy Casburn's* comment (new user = low rep = cannot comment).

"change `.slice(1)` to `.slice(-100)` - negative values pulls from the end of the array. – *Randy Casburn*
"

You will likely want to add a default variable to your function.

```
. . . = async (path, nValues=-1)
```

and alter your slice to be

```
. . . ('\n').slice(-nValues).map((row)
```

Note that the default of `-1` is the same as `.slice(1)` because we use `-nValues`

This should add the functionality you want without forcing the user to know how many lines they want. You do not want to needlessly limit your function.

Comment: Thank you BadAtMaths for adding description to the answer! It was more simple then i thinked but was helpfull! Thank you and Happy Holidays

Comment: You've added a good explanation. I'll add some rep so you can help others :-)